# java method is returning correctly but also changing the initial argument

Tags: java, methods

this is for the fifteen game, I made a class (Config), which consists of an array of ints to represent the state of the board.
then I made some move methods which receive  Config A, create a copy of it,finds its 0 and applies whatever move the method is supposed to and then returning it as Config B.
thats happening as plan but the problem is that when I try to print config A afterwards it also changed, and is the same as B no matter what move I do.
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHPmH.jpg dada.tabela is the array

if I print randomconfig before the move_left_new, it prints the original config as it should, however if I print it afterwards, it will print the same as testingmove.

```
import java.util.*;
class Config{
int[] tabela;


Config(){
int[] blanks ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0};
tabela = blanks;
}
public Config(int arraydado[]){
tabela = arraydado;}
 public void printTabela(){
for(int i = 0; i<16 ;i++)
    System.out.print(tabela[i] + " ");
System.out.println();
}
}
    public static Config move_left_new(Config dada){
    int i;
    int temp;
    Config resultante = new Config(dada.tabela);
    for(i = 0; i<16; i++){
    if(resultante.tabela[i] == 0)
        break;
    }
    if( i!=0 && i!= 4 && i!= 8 && i!=12){
    temp = resultante.tabela[i-1];
    resultante.tabela[i-1] = 0;
    resultante.tabela[i] = temp;
    }
    return resultante;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int arr[] = new int[16];
for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
arr[i] = input.nextInt();

Config randomconfig = new Config(arr);
randomconfig.printTabela(); //original
Config changed = move_left_new(randomconfig);
randomconfig.printTabela(); //should be the same as before but isnt
changed.printTabela(); // moved as it should
}
```

Comment: Post all code here directly as text. Why would you post text as an image?

Comment: theres a lot more stuff thats irrelevant to this, but Ill paste the main parts here as text

Comment: please also add the code when you create the copy of ConfigA

Comment: @Rodrigo  I realy realy love seing code in non english. It reminds me of the Norwegian public sector. By the way the -1 was not me :)

Comment: @Rodrigo That's why code you post should be a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: @carcigenicate yeah, sorry, its my first time posting here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Arrays are references in java. So after you do `Config resultante = new Config(dada.tabela);`, the `tabela` of `resultance` and `dada` would both refer/point to the same array.

What you might want to do, is to create a shallow copy of `dada.tabela`, then pass that shallow copy to Config's constructor to instantiate `resultante`.

Try:

```
Config resultante = new Config(dada.tabela.clone());
```

or

```
Config resultante = new Config(Arrays.copyOf(dada.tabela, dada.tabela.length));
```